# Elastic Beanstalk not executing hooks: "skipping hooks scripts under /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux-2

I'm trying to get Elastic Beanstalk (Amazon Linux 2, Node.js 16) to run some pre-deploy hooks. I'm using .ebextensions to create a hook in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/.

In .ebextensions, I have a file, 04_use_yarn.config:

```
files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/49yarn.sh":
        mode:    "000775"
        owner:   root
        group:   users
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            # <Contents of the script I'm trying to run>
```

When SSHing into the instance, I can see that the 49yarn.sh file in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/ is generated correctly. But during the deploy, I see that it logs "**[WARN] skipping hooks scripts under /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/**". I can't find any documentation about what would make it skip the hooks in that directory.

How can I make it not skip my hook?

Here are the relevant logs from eb-engine.log:

```
2022/05/26 20:28:29.538686 [INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
2022/05/26 20:28:30.060239 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2022/05/26 20:28:30.060268 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2022/05/26 20:28:36.070529 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2022/05/26 20:28:36.176851 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2022/05/26 20:28:36.176873 [WARN] skipping hooks scripts under /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/
2022/05/26 20:28:36.176890 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/prebuild/
2022/05/26 20:28:36.176934 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist
2022/05/26 20:28:36.176946 [INFO] Finished running scripts in /var/app/staging/.platform/hooks/prebuild
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html):

> On Amazon Linux 2 platforms, custom platform hooks in the `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/` folder are entirely discontinued. **Elastic Beanstalk doesn't read or execute them.**

This is why the script(s) are being skipped.

You will need to migrate over to [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).